# When one checkbox is checked in a group, disable & uncheck all other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So in the code below,

```js
function listen(element, event, callback) {
  if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
  } else {
    element.addEventListener(event, callback);
  }
}

var form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
listen(form, 'click', function (event) {
  var checkBoxes, i, checked, target;
  target = event.srcElement || event.target;
  if (target.getAttribute('name') === 'check1') {
    checkBoxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[name="check2"]');
    checked = target.checked;
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      checkBoxes[i].disabled = checked && checkBoxes[i] !== target;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '1'>Report 1    </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '2'>R1 Option 1 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '3'>R1 Option 2 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '4'>R1 Option 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '5'>Report 2    </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '6'>R2 Option 1 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '7'>R2 Option 2 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '8'>R2 Option 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '5'>Report 3    </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '6'>R3 Option 1 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '7'>R3 Option 2 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '8'>R3 Option 3 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Report 1 is checked, Report 2 and Report 3 as well as all the options for Report 2 and Report 3 should be un-checked and not selectable. I only want the user to be able to select one report at a time, with the options for that report only to be available for selection. 
Any assistance is much appreciated.

Snippet:-

Comment: It's not an answer you're looking for, but why not use a radiogroup instead? (styled as checkboxes if you need that visual look)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input').on('change', function () {
        $('input').not(this).attr('disabled', true);
      });
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      $('input').on('change', function () {
        $('input').not(this).attr('disabled', false);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '1'>Report 1    </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '2'>R1 Option 1 </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '3'>R1 Option 2 </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '4'>R1 Option 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '5'>Report 2    </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '6'>R2 Option 1 </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '7'>R2 Option 2 </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '8'>R2 Option 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '5'>Report 3    </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '6'>R3 Option 1 </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '7'>R3 Option 2 </td>
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '8'>R3 Option 3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple validation

```js
$("#myForm").find("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
if ($(this).is(":checked"))
{
$("#myForm").find("input[type='checkbox']").not($(this)).prop("disabled", true)
}else 
{
$("#myForm").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false)
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '1'>Report 1    </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '2'>R1 Option 1 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '3'>R1 Option 2 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '4'>R1 Option 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '5'>Report 2    </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '6'>R2 Option 1 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '7'>R2 Option 2 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check2' value = '8'>R2 Option 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '5'>Report 3    </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '6'>R3 Option 1 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '7'>R3 Option 2 </td>
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='check3' value = '8'>R3 Option 3 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```